# Software to convert tensor into vector?

Tags: tensors, computational-mathematics

I would like to simplify $\boldsymbol{\nabla}\cdot\boldsymbol{\sigma}_{brag}$, given by:

[image: viscosity tensor]

taken from [this](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-fluid-mechanics/article/braginskii-magnetohydrodynamics-for-arbitrary-magnetic-topologies-coronal-applications/B223D074539703D217B072378A369FD8) paper. For a magnetic field, $\vec{B}$, of the form
$$\vec{B}=(0,b(x,z),B_0),$$
and velocity,
$$\vec{u}=(0,u(x,z),0).$$
It seems like too much effort to do this manually, especially since I have almost no knowledge of tensor calculus. Does anyone know how I could get a computer to do this? I have maple but not Mathematica.

Comment: Here the tensor product seems to be used in the place of a dyadic product, $a\otimes b=ab^\top$. This should be sufficiently easy to impement.

Comment: Maple can do an outer product in the linear algebra package. How would I get it to take the divergence of the resultant matrix?

Comment: Be careful, usually (IMO, YMMV) an outer product is a proper tensor product which is anti-symmetric, $a\wedge b$ is a multiple of $a\otimes b-b\otimes a$. This is not what you want.

Comment: Would you mind demonstrating how you would calculate say $$\boldsymbol{\nabla}\cdot\boldsymbol{W}^{(0)}$$ as I could then extend your code to find the rest?